# Group of 9 people, with(out) 3 people who all know each other

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

**Problem:**
*In a group of nine people, one person knows
two of the others, two people each know four others,
four each know five others, and the remaining two each
know six others. Show that there are three people who
all know each other.*

**My Solution (asking for verification):**
I want to show that we cant construct a graph with 9 vertices, obeying the given conditions, that does not include a subgraph with a cycle where 3 people all know each other.
If you have another solution, please tell me (I believe there is a much easier one).
Excuse my poor drawing skills with a mouse :D

**EDIT:I noticed, that the second step doesnt really minimize mutual friendship but the argument works the same after a few steps since we end up in the same position where we cant get further without creating that cycle!**

Order a graph with 9  vertices from "knows the least" to "knows a lot of people"
[image: nuumb1]

Start to connect from left to right, "minimizing overlap in friendship."

[image: nuumb2]

Coming to the conclusion that from this point on we cant let the People(vertices) have more friends, because that would result in mutual friendship among 3 people.

[image: nuumb3]

I dont know if that is enough, would appreciate some help.
Im pretty sure there exists an easier answer but I really wanted to think about the problem in that way.

Comment: I find it unclear why your answer is a correct one. How would you convince me that you do not miss any cases?

Comment: A possibly overkill solution is to notice that the friendship graph has 21 edges, and that a triangle-free graph with 9 vertices can only have at most 20 edges. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142707/maximum-number-of-edges-in-an-n-vertex-triangle-free-simple-graph-is-lfloor for a general proof of the maximum number  of edges in a triangle-free graph.

Comment: @VTand I would say every graph that satisfies the requirements is just a slight variation in what order you draw the lines. But you have to draw the lines and after some steps, no matter where you draw them - you will end up constructing this triangle. (Big thanks for the link, i like your solution better)

Comment: @chopin44 In particular, you seem to be assuming that the person with $2$ friends knows the two people with $4$ friends, which is not fully general.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I see. Makes sense, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start from the person who knows $2$ people, you have to consider who those $2$ friends are. They could have $4$ friends, $5$ friends, and $6$ friends, and while all of those cases lead to a triangle, you do have to consider all of them.

Start from a person who knows $6$ people instead: it's quicker, you don't have to do multiple steps, and you don't have to do casework on who is friends with whom.

If there is a friendship within that set of $6$ people, we're done. Otherwise, each of them is friends with at most $3$ people (the number outside the set). But there is only one person who's allowed to have fewer than $3$ friends; everyone else has at least $4$. Contradiction!

Comment: Misha, the answer is the number of edges in a turan graph with no triangle and 9 vertices, no? I don't remember the details (or even the notation), but I think that's it.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes A "Turan graph with no triangle and $9$ vertices" is just a complete bipartite graph $K_{4,5}$, with $20$ edges. So you could also argue that since this graph has more than $20$ edges, it can't be triangle-free. But I wanted to give a self-contained argument.

Comment: And that was the best thing you could do since I have no idea about Turan Graphs, but yet I learned much from the whole post!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm more of concept checking myself. I know you are a graph-theorist that's why I took the opportunity